# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property `value` of undefined" при использовании события on

Tags: javascript, jquery

Браузер пишет ошибку на первой строчке:
[image]

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.submit_user_details', function() {
        document.formvalidator = new JFormValidator();
        userForm.task.value = 'savecartuser'; //this is a method to set the task of the form on the fTask.
        if (document.formvalidator.isValid(userForm)) {
            $.post(window.location.href+"&tmpl=component", $(this).serialize()).done(function(data) {
                window.fb.close(true);
                form = $('form[name=checkoutForm]');
                $.post(form.attr('action')+"&tmpl=component", form.serialize()).done(function(data) {
                    window.fb.open(data);
                });
            });
        } else {
            var msg = '<?php echo addslashes (JText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_USER_FORM_MISSING_REQUIRED_JS')); ?>';
            alert(msg + ' ');
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Не могу понять, в чем проблема, при переходе Step Into в отладчике страница перезагружается. jQuery 1.6.4

Answer (score 3):

События "[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)" и "[.off](http://api.jquery.com/off/)" появились в jQuery, начиная c версии 1.7

Вам следует обновить [версию jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/).

Comment: Обновил, ошибка осталась, в том же самом месте. Но Step Into теперь возможен.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, не найден сам объект на странице:

1. Проверьте, что до момента вызова кода, объект присутствует в DOM дереве.
2. И что код находится внутри `$(document).ready(function(e){ ...your code hear... });`

Comment: 1. На момент выполнения кода присутствует.
2. Это так.

Answer (score 0):

Единственное место в коде, где вы выставляете значение проперти`value` это:

```
userForm.task.value = 'savecartuser';
```

Проверьте, что существует `userForm`, и что у `userForm` есть поле `task`.